# Center figure label text in box with caption label text

Tags: floats, captions, vertical-alignment

In the code given below that is extracted from [Harvey Sheppards's template](https://github.com/HarveySheppard), I wanted to know how to get the caption label text to line up with the text in the colored box? This is the effect that I am trying to get:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{yLabel}{%
\tikz{\node[anchor=west, inner sep=2mm, fill=blue, font=\bfseries, text=white]{#1 #2};}
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{yReportCaptionStyle}{labelsep=none, labelformat=yLabel, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup*[figure]{style=yReportCaptionStyle, justification=RaggedRight, position=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{This is an example figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the baseline of the tikz picture to be the baseline of the text node:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{yLabel}{%
\tikz[baseline=(T.base)]{\node (T)[anchor=west, inner sep=2mm, fill=blue, font=\bfseries, text=white]{#1 #2};}
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{yReportCaptionStyle}{labelsep=none, labelformat=yLabel, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup*[figure]{style=yReportCaptionStyle, justification=RaggedRight, position=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{This is an example figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why use a hammer-sledge like TikZ when a simple `colorbox` easily does the job?

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor, caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bgLabel}{%
\colorbox{RoyalBlue}{\color{white}\bfseries#1 #2}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{yReportCaptionStyle}{labelformat=bgLabel, labelsep=space, justification=RaggedRight, position =bottom, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup*[figure]{style=yReportCaptionStyle, justification=RaggedRight, position=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\caption{This is an example figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `\raisebox` command to archive this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{yLabel}{%
\tikz{\node[anchor=west, inner sep=2mm, fill=blue, font=\bfseries, text=white]{#1 #2};}
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{yReportCaptionStyle}{labelsep=none, labelformat=yLabel, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup*[figure]{style=yReportCaptionStyle, justification=RaggedRight, position=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{\raisebox{2.6mm}{This is an example figure}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]